# componentone c1calendar display a popup calendar and set the selected date in the textbox javascript error

Tags: ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, componentone

I am using this code to show a javascript error.

```
function SelectDate()
{
    var calendar = Sys.Application.findComponent("C1Calendar1.ClientID");
    var input = document.getElementById("TextBoxDate");
    calendar.popupBeside(input, C1.Web.Wijmo.PositioningMode.bottomLeft);
}
```

Comment: function SelectDate()
       {
          var calendar = Sys.Application.findComponent("C1Calendar1.ClientID");
          var input = document.getElementById("TextBoxDate");
          calendar.popupBeside(input, C1.Web.Wijmo.PositioningMode.bottomLeft);
      }

      function CalendarClosed()
       {
          var calendar = Sys.Application.findComponent("C1Calendar1.ClientID");
          var input = document.getElementById("TextBoxDate");
          input.value = calendar.get_selectedDate().toLocaleDateString();
      }

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'popupBeside': object is null or undefined  SHOW THE ERROR

Comment: can i solve the problem?

Comment: Every problem can be solved, but just for some problemes nobody has found a solution yet (like the many unsolved problems of maths). So I think the answer would be yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about c# but I think there could be several possibilites why it doesn't work. Just try out if it is one of these with your debugger or something like that...

- `calendar` may be undefined, because it could possible doesn't found.
- `calendar` may be the wrong type, perhaps a primitive type.
- `calendar` may don't have the popupBeside method.

If it isn't one of those, I also don't know what the problem is. As said I have really no experience with C# so this are just some ideas what could be wrong.